# How can I change the value of a key in the JSON objects array before being saved into the react state

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I want to be able to change the profileUrl value from a hyperlink to a different string.

I need to be able to check and change for 6 different profileUrls, as my **scraping** service is **scraping** 6 different linkedIn profiles.

JSON end point:
https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json

Component:

```
// LinkedIn Component Class
export default class LinkedIn extends React.Component<ILinkedInProps, ILinkedInState> {

  // Grabs LinkedIn profiles - This service runs once a day
  private getProfiles() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
        "https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          profiles: response.data.filter(d=>d.postContent&&d.imgUrl) 
        });
      })
      // Error catching
      .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "change one of the values"? Do you want to store that value permanently so that it is returned by future calls to the end point? Or do you want to edit it in memory for the current state of your program?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you give an example (before and after) by editing the question?

Comment: Also, did you write this API? Or are you using an API that someone else created?

Comment: Sorry I will rewrite the question. Its a phantom buster linkedin scrapping service. I have no controll over the key/values.

Comment: Done! @SuleymanSah

Comment: Still not very clear,  do you want to get only 6 items from the response?   profiles: response.data.filter(d=>d.postContent&&d.imgUrl)

Comment: @SuleymanSah I just want to be able to change the profileUrl to the companys name instead of the Url for each object, before being saved into the state.

Comment: Just... literally do what you ask? You get an array of objects, and you want to rename a property in those objects. Renaming doesn't exist in JS, but "creating and deleting any property you want" is, so just do that. `response.data.map(d => fixElement(d))` and make fixElement do `d.newthing = d.oldthing; delete d.oldthing; return d;`?

Comment: can you check my answer?

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

After filter, we can use map to transform our data as we want.
Here we add a new property companyName.

I assume your 6 companies is in companies array.

```
export default class LinkedIn extends React.Component<ILinkedInProps, ILinkedInState> {

  companies =  ["https://www.linkedin.com/company/abf-ingredients", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5", "link6"];

  // Grabs LinkedIn profiles - This service runs once a day
  private getProfiles() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
        "https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          profiles: response.data.filter(d=>d.postContent&&d.imgUrl && this.companies.includes(d.profileUrl)).map(item => {
            return {
                ...item,
                companyName: this.companies.find(link => link === item.profileUrl )
            }
          }) 
        });
      })
      // Error catching
      .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

For one item I give before and after cases.

Before:

```
 {
    "postUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6587985299538759680",
    "action": "Post",
    "postContent": "Today is",
    "imgUrl": "https://media-exp1...",
    "likeCount": 13,
    "commentCount": 3,
    "postDate": "1d",
    "viewCount": "",
    "profileUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/abf-ingredients",
    "timestamp": "2019-10-11T16:00:04.819Z"
  }
```

After:

```
{
  "postUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6587985299538759680",
  "action": "Post",
  "postContent": "Today is ...",
  "imgUrl": "https://media-exp1...",
  "likeCount": 13,
  "commentCount": 3,
  "postDate": "1d",
  "viewCount": "",
  "profileUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/abf-ingredients",
  "timestamp": "2019-10-11T16:00:04.819Z",
  "companyName": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/abf-ingredients"
}
```

Or if you want all items, you can use this:

```
    profiles: response.data.filter(d=>d.postContent&&d.imgUrl).map(item => {
            return {
                ...item,
                companyName:   companies.find(link => link === item.profileUrl) ? item.profileUrl: ""
            }
          })
```

Comment: I can set a new property with this method, however it does not work when I try overwriting the property for profileUrl. Mike said this is not possible?

Anyways the new value for profileUrl will depend on which object, there are 6 different profileUrls, so its a bit tricky then what you suggested. 

Thank god I am meeting up with my senior js friend this weekend lmao.

Comment: @BennKingy  I dont add a new property, please try and see.

Comment: where will come companyName from? I can try to adjust answer.

Comment: Thank you for trying man. There are 6 different potential values for the ProfileUrl property depending on which object. So if PropfileUrl = link1 then make it 'Company name1' . If ProfileUrl = link2 then make it 'Company name2'. Or just add a new property for the company name. But there is 6 diffrent companys and I want to be able to render each company name further down my component. Thats why I am trying to add this.

Comment: @BennKingy I gave another try by editing answer, does it help you?